# Added params to windows.location now page doesn't want to redirect to required form

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

When button is clicked, I want the page to show an `alert` window, and thereafter redirect the user to a different form. Initially there were no parameters added and the code worked as I wanted it to. After adding the parameters, the pages does not redirect to the form.

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('Customer visit record for the visit has been created.You will now be taken to customer visit process.');"
                            + "window.location='CustomerVisit.aspx?bookingID="+cust_visit.BookingID.ToString()+
                            "&customerID="+cust_visit.CustomerID.ToString()+"</script>");
```

I want to add the parameters so that I can use them in the next form using:

```
Request.QueryString["bookingID"]
```

Comment: You're missing a closing single quote for the location url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close the single-quote for the value of the `location`, and it is recommended to follow it with the semicolon:

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('...');"
    + "window.location = 'CustomerVisit.aspx?bookingID=" + cust_visit.BookingID.ToString()
    + "&customerID=" + cust_visit.CustomerID.ToString() + "';</script>");
```

Comment: I'm not sure you're correct about not being able to concatenate with a + for C# objects in this case. Since it's a `Response.Write`, it's almost certainly happening in the code behind, where the object should be available.

Comment: @JonathonChase You're absolutely right. I don't know why I had the impression that the code was on a view instead of code-behind or controller. I think the question got mixed up in my head with another question I was trying to answer. I corrected the answer and removed that part. Thank you for the note.